# Relation between quasilinear utility and quasilinear function

Tags: economics

When we say Quasilinear utility, it is known that function is linear in numeraire. It is expected to be linear in one argument and hence it can be called ***quasi***linear. Can any one tell me if there is any relation between this definition and [quasilinear function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) (function which is both quasiconvex and quasiconcave)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No relationship between the two other than the names.